# Upright greek math: `theta` with `textgreek` package too boldish

Tags: fonts, math-mode, greek

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
Normal text default font, italics and upright:

\textit{\straighttheta\straighttheta\straighttheta}\straighttheta\straighttheta\straighttheta \ (upright font is not correct)\\

Greek math, standard and upright (adjusted font):

$\theta\theta\theta\textnormal{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\straighttheta\straighttheta\straighttheta}$  (upright theta is too bold)\\

Latin math, standard and upright:

$xxx\mathrm{xxx}$
\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image]

I don't know if it is typographically correct, but to me the upright `theta` seems too boldish compared with the italics of the standard math mode.

How can I get a correct upright `theta`?

I also tried to "artificially" enlighten `theta` using the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2517029), but was not able to adapt it to the right font.

Comment: Possible alternative for your case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Answer (score 5):

The upright theta in these examples is **not** typographically correct.

Here's the problem. "Standard" Computer Modern does not "come" with upright greek letters, but with a slanted letter. The `textgreek` package provides a way around that problem, by using the `cbgreek` font, and defining `\texttheta` and so forth to "borrow" from them.

And that is fine ... but the `cbgreek` font uses the style of theta that looks like example (a) in the illustration below, not (b). These are not different letters, but variant forms of the theta (though unicode assigns separate numbers so that both can be present in a single font).

[image: greek thetas]

What then happens is that, in order to try to provide a non-script version of theta, `textgreek` is "borrowing" from either the Euler font (which is what is shown in your first example) or -- I think -- the symbol font (which occurs in your second, because you select Helvetica which `textgreek` "maps" to symbol).

Since these thetas were designed for quite different fonts they are a very poor match for computer modern -- each has a quite different design, weight and so forth.

Here are a few ideas:

- Put up with a bad looking straight theta (OK, pehaps, if you only use it in one place).
- Accept the scriptstyle theta that is part of the `cbgreek` font, and load `textgreek` and use `\texttheta`.
- Take a quite different approach to greek letters outside maths, for instance by using XeLaTeX which will enable you to use unicode and any font you choose (though you will then have to consider matching math fonts).
- Redefine `\straighttheta`. For instance, if you load the `lgreek` package (which has a different font, with a straight theta) you can redefine the `\straighttheta` command of `textgreek` to be `{\begin{greek}j\end{greek}}` However, although that produces a somewhat better match (I think) in some respects, it has its own problems in your example, because there is no slanted version of the `lgreek` font. But it's OK with math, because the math letters get taken from Computer Modern. The picture below shows an `lgreek` based theta in text alongside CM theta in math.

[image: using lgreek]

Comment: idea#1: I'm refining for good looking `theta`, so this one is rejected
idea#2: same as before, `theta` style is too different
idea#3: don't know XeLaTeX, don't want to change the way I work
idea#4: could not get `lgreek` package working, I get `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lgreek\lgcmr.fd")
! Font LG/cmr/m/n/10=grreg10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file.` error in MWE `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{greek}j\end{greek}
\end{document}`

Comment: Well, apart from suggesting you make sure that the lgreek package and its dependencies have been installed, I can't help much beyond the usually infuriating comment that it works here!

Comment: I'm not able to fully understand the meaning of your comment, but I'd like to assure you that I appreciate very much your answer and with my comment I was just trying to be concise, hope you didn't take it for rudeness. About the non-working MWE for idea#4, you can check it here too: https://www.writelatex.com/95553mmdmkw

Comment: I didn't think you were being rude at all! By "infuriating" I meant infuriating to you: it's not much help to be told "well, it works for me", but sometimes there's not much more that can be said from afar. Sorry if I was not clear.