# Environment for non-cursive symbol in article?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[amsmath]
\begin{document}
ionizing collisions is about $132 \, \mu \text{m}$
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

where I think the $\mu$ should be not cursive. 
I tried unsuccessfully putting the symbol within the text -environment.

What is the correct environment of the symbol for non-cursive text?

Comment: Would this answer suffice: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220?

Comment: I inserted the definition to the top and added *unslant* at the beginning of the *\mu* and run in XeLaTeX but get *Undefined control sequence*. Can you give a specific example for *article* in XeLaTeX, please.

Comment: The cited approach works in pdflatex, but apparently the pdf specials are not available to xelatex.

Comment: In your case I'd strongly suggest using siunitx to typeset your numbers with units.  From this brief snippet I'd make a wild guess that you're going to be printing rather a lot of number/unit pairs.  The mu for microns is handled correctly there.  You  are correct that the SI governing body says the mu shoudl be upright: http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure

Comment: @ChrisH To all cases? I am thinking where is the borderline. Like for `$N_{P} = 27$ ion pairs/cm` too?

Comment: I believe there's no reason why you can't do things like ion pairs/cm, either by setting up a new unit or as `ion pair\si{\per\centi\metre}` (which is probably how I'd do it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `textcomp` symbols (encoding `TS1`) contains an upright `\textmu`. An alternative for setting numbers and units offer the powerful package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
ionizing collisions is about $132 \, \text{\textmu m}$
or \SI{132}{\micro\meter}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]