# Greek letters \rm mode, MikTeX

Tags: greek

The question sounds simple - how to write greek math symbol, say, `$\alpha$` to get alpha's text mode (straight, like after \rm) but still in formula ? Any packages? Thanks!

Comment: Package `upgreek` or use a font which has both versions (not the case for the default Computer Modern).

Comment: upgreek contains upright greek letters of a fixed font which works fine for Computer Modern, a more general solution using a new command `\unslant` is presented [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313934/sans-serif-upright-greek-in-math-mode). In both cases you still need something like `\upalpha`, but [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277571/create-and-use-macro-names-dynamically-within-a-loop-for-redefining-lowercase-gr/277577#277577) helps you to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, upgreek works good for me. Hope it works good for publisher)

Comment: Don't use `\rm` with LaTeX

Comment: Ok, Christian) I don't, thats for bad example.

Comment: See also here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern