# Use smart greek letters recognizing \mathrm with mathastext-package

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, greek, mathastext

This is another follow-up question to [**this one**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277571/36835) with [**@wipet's great answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277577/36835) on how to create "smart greek letters" which in math mode are normally italic, but recognize the `\mathrm` command to become upright.

I was using this setup successfully with various math fonts, but since I'm newly supposed to use *Open Sans* as text font in my presentation, I'm not so happy with the *sansmathfonts* package anymore. So I thought give *mathastext* a try. I already successfully declared a greek math alphabet, but `\usepackage{mathastext}` breaks @wipet's `\setsmartgreek`.

I don't really understand why, as mathastext is supposed to leave the greek letters untouched by default. I also tried various other package options. **Is there a way to get the smart greek letters working again?**

### Original MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Load fonts, sansmathfonts for symbols etc.
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}

% Declare greek letters for math
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreek}{LGR}{fos}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreek}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreekit}{LGR}{fos}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreekit}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{bx}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\muup}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{osgreekit}{`m}

% set smart greek letters
\def\setsmartgreek{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname muup\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{##2up}\fi
    \expandafter\ifx\csname upmu\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{up##2}\fi
    \ifx\stgreekC\undefined \errmessage{upright greek letters are not available}%
    \else \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}
\def\setsmartgreekA#1{\ifx#1\relax \else
    \expandafter \let \csname it:\string#1\endcsname = #1%
    \edef#1{\noexpand\ifnum\fam=0
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname\expandafter\stgreekC\string#1;\endcsname
        \noexpand\else \expandafter\noexpand\csname it:\string#1\endcsname
        \noexpand\fi}%
    \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}

\setsmartgreek\mu\relax

% substitute letters and numbers with text font in math mode
\usepackage{mathastext} %<--- comment out and smart greek letters work

% siunitx should keep working
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-micro=\mathrm{\upmu}}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{detect-all}}

\begin{document}

Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}

\textit{Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}

\textbf{Bold numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}

\textbf{\textit{Bold italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}}

\[
\int \sum X_\mathrm{\textcolor{red}{\mu\upmu}}\mu\upmu\mathrm{\textcolor{red}{\mu\upmu}}A + 2 = \SI{42}{\micro\meter\ampere\gram}
\]

All \textcolor{red}{red} should be upright. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Extended MWE

The [answer of jfbu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398499/36835) suggests to use the option `defaultrm` or `defaultalphabets` of **mathastext**, which works for the original MWE. But for normal letters the font falls back to `sansmathfonts` inside `\mathrm`. Without `defaultrm` the smart greek letters don't work, but the fonts are right. Is there any solution?

The manual of mathastext is quite frustrating to read on that topic, there is an extended discussion, but it does not really get to point unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{fosrm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosrm}{m}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/l/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosrm}{b}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosrm}{m}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/l/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosrm}{b}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/it}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{fossf}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fossf}{m}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/m/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fossf}{b}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fossf}{m}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fossf}{b}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/b/it}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{LGR}{fosgreek}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{m}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/l/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{b}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{m}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/l/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{b}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/it}{}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fossf}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fosrm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand{\mddefault}{m}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\mddefault}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreek}{LGR}{fos}{l}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreek}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{sb}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}

\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreekit}{LGR}{fos}{l}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreekit}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{sb}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{osgreekit}{`m}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\muup}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{osgreekit}{`m}

% set smart greek letters
\def\setsmartgreek{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname muup\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{##2up}\fi
    \expandafter\ifx\csname upmu\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{up##2}\fi
    \ifx\stgreekC\undefined \errmessage{upright greek letters are not available}%
    \else \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}
\def\setsmartgreekA#1{\ifx#1\relax \else
    \expandafter \let \csname it:\string#1\endcsname = #1%
    \edef#1{\noexpand\ifnum\fam=0
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname\expandafter\stgreekC\string#1;\endcsname
        \noexpand\else \expandafter\noexpand\csname it:\string#1\endcsname
        \noexpand\fi}%
    \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}

\setsmartgreek\mu\relax

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textmu}{{\usefont{LGR}{fosgreek}{\f@series}{\f@shape}\symbol{\string"6D}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textohm}{{\usefont{LGR}{fosgreek}{\f@series}{\f@shape}\symbol{\string"5F}}}
\makeatother
\sisetup{math-rm=\textrm, math-sf=\textrm,
         math-micro=\upmu,text-micro=\textmu,
         math-ohm=\upOmega,text-ohm=\textohm}

\usepackage[italic,defaultrm]{mathastext}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-all}

Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}\par
\textit{Regular italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}\par
\textbf{Bold numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}\par
\textbf{\textit{Bold italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}}\par

\[
\int \sum \sin X_\mathrm{\textcolor{purple}{xA}\textcolor{red}{\mu\upmu}}xA\mu\upmu\mathrm{\textcolor{purple}{xA}\textcolor{red}{\mu\upmu}} + 2 = \SI{42}{\micro\meter\ampere\gram}
\]

All \textcolor{red}{red} should be upright. 

All \textcolor{purple}{purple} should be in the same font as the rest. 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @wipet this is a follow-up question to your [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277577/36835).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my initial answer I did not even check the @wipet `\setsmartgreek` code. My initial answer suggested using `defaultrm` option to `mathastext` because this prevents the package of modifying the font with which `\mathrm` works. But in comments it was reported this cancels too much of `mathastext` influence. So I checked `\setsmartgreek`'s code and perhaps one only needs to use this modified version:

```
% substitute letters and numbers with text font in math mode
\usepackage{mathastext}

% set smart greek letters (adapted to mathastext presence; see \ifnum test)
\def\setsmartgreek{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname muup\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{##2up}\fi
    \expandafter\ifx\csname upmu\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{up##2}\fi
    \ifx\stgreekC\undefined \errmessage{upright greek letters are not available}%
    \else \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}
\def\setsmartgreekA#1{\ifx#1\relax \else
    \expandafter \let \csname it:\string#1\endcsname = #1%
    \edef#1{\noexpand\ifnum\fam=\symmtoperatorfont
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname\expandafter\stgreekC\string#1;\endcsname
        \noexpand\else \expandafter\noexpand\csname it:\string#1\endcsname
        \noexpand\fi}%
    \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}

\setsmartgreek\mu\relax
```

It works in my testing with the OP's MWE.

**Addition by OP:**

The above answer just seems to work in case the [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer)-class is used. In other cases (e.g. KOMA-script, article) it causes an error, not apparent with the old macro defintion. A simple check for the loaded class can solve this issue:

```
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{
    \def\familyidentifier{\symmtoperatorfont}
    }{
    \def\familyidentifier{0}
}
```

An within the macro the related line has to be changed to:

```
\edef#1{\noexpand\ifnum\fam=\familyidentifier
        ...
        }%
```

---

---

former answer:

Pass option `defaultrm`  to `mathastext`, or probably better the all-encompassing `defaultalphabets`. (check details in the [doc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext))

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Load fonts, sansmathfonts for symbols etc.
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}

% Declare greek letters for math
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreek}{LGR}{fos}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreek}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreekit}{LGR}{fos}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreekit}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{bx}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\muup}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{osgreekit}{`m}

% set smart greek letters
\def\setsmartgreek{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname muup\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{##2up}\fi
    \expandafter\ifx\csname upmu\endcsname\relax 
    \else \def\stgreekC##1##2;{up##2}\fi
    \ifx\stgreekC\undefined \errmessage{upright greek letters are not available}%
    \else \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}
\def\setsmartgreekA#1{\ifx#1\relax \else
    \expandafter \let \csname it:\string#1\endcsname = #1%
    \edef#1{\noexpand\ifnum\fam=0
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname\expandafter\stgreekC\string#1;\endcsname
        \noexpand\else \expandafter\noexpand\csname it:\string#1\endcsname
        \noexpand\fi}%
    \expandafter\setsmartgreekA \fi
}

\setsmartgreek\mu\relax

% substitute letters and numbers with text font in math mode
\usepackage[defaultrm]{mathastext}

% siunitx should keep working
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-micro=\mathrm{\upmu}}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{detect-all}}

\begin{document}

Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}

\textit{Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}

\textbf{Bold numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}

\textbf{\textit{Bold italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}}

\[
\int \sum X_\mathrm{\textcolor{red}{\mu\upmu}}\mu\upmu\mathrm{\textcolor{red}{\mu\upmu}}A + 2 = \SI{42}{\micro\meter\ampere\gram}
\]

All \textcolor{red}{red} should be upright. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Indeed, `mathastext` by default changes nothing to Greek letters. But it does define its own versions of the math alphabets (in order to use the correct -- in its view! -- fonts).

Comment: `defaultrm` works, `defaultalphabets` makes siunitx use the math font again in math mode. thanks!

Comment: the mathastext customized math alphabet is still available as `\Mathrm` (with capital `M`) in case you need it. Thanks for the infor about impact with siunitx of `defaultalphabets`.

Comment: I realized, the effect of `defaultrm` and `defaultalphabets` depends on the siunitx settings. However, both cause `\mathrm` to use `sansmathfont` again. Do you know an easy solution for this? Otherwise I ask a new question. The manual is quite confusing on this.

Comment: unfortunately I have to unaccept this answer, as defaultrm breaks more than it fixes. A new question would be surely a duplicate though. Do you mind if I offer a bounty on the extended question?

Comment: I had not even read `\setsmartgreek`'s code. Perhaps simplest is to modify it by replacing `\ifnum\fam=0<space>` test by `\ifnum\fam=\symmtoperatorfont`. Try it out. Package `mathastext` must be loaded before.

Comment: of wait, no, why did i fix my answer before the bounty! silly me!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you want the bounty anyway? :D

Comment: the green tick will make my day ;)

Comment: I made an addition to your answer too long for a comment, please rollback if you disagree or have a better solution.

Comment: @thewaywewalk fine with me, however `\def\familyidentifier{0}` should be `\def\familyidentifier{0 }` with a space after the `0` else the `\ifnum` test might misbehave (not in this particular case, but just to have good practice). The `\symmtoperatorfont` is not a macro but a chardef thing, and no space is needed after it to properly terminate it.