# Make \mathrm produce upright greek

Tags: math-mode, greek, roman

I need to distinguish between italic and upright greek letters. I use the `alphabeta` package for that. This allows me to write e.g. an upright `\mu` in mathmode by typing `$\text\mu$`. Can I extend this in such a way that also `\mathrm` produces the upright `\mu`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{is italic mu: } & \mu \mathit \mu\\
\text{should be upright mu: } & \text \mu \mathrm \mu
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While it won't have your desired syntax, and is limited to pdflatex, the approach here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220, permits the unslanting of slanted Greek glyphs.

Comment: An idea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277576/82917

Comment: Also relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277571/create-and-use-macro-names-dynamically-within-a-loop-for-redefining-lowercase-gr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution for `pdftex`. Wildly untested, so there might be issues I haven't thought of. Note that `alphabeta` *cannot* be loaded, but its basic functionality is provided.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% for \text
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\makeatletter

\def\@tempa#1#2#3{%
   \let#2=#1
   \def#1{\TextOrMath{#3}{\ifnum\fam=0 \text{#3}\else#2\fi}}%
}

\@tempa\alpha\mathalpha\textalpha
\@tempa\beta\mathbeta\textbeta
\@tempa\gamma\mathgamma\textgamma
\@tempa\delta\mathdelta\textdelta
\@tempa\epsilon\mathepsilon\textepsilon
\@tempa\zeta\mathzeta\textzeta
\@tempa\eta\matheta\texteta
\@tempa\theta\maththeta\texttheta
\@tempa\vartheta\mathvartheta\texttheta
\@tempa\iota\mathiota\textiota
\@tempa\kappa\mathkappa\textkappa
\@tempa\lambda\mathlambda\textlambda
\@tempa\mu\mathmu\textmu
\@tempa\mnu\mathmnu\textmnu
\@tempa\xi\mathxi\textxi
\@tempa\rho\mathrho\textrho
\@tempa\varrho\mathvarrho\textrho
\@tempa\sigma\mathsigma\textsigma
\@tempa\tau\mathtau\texttau
\@tempa\upsilon\mathupsilon\textupsilon
\@tempa\phi\mathphi\textphi
\@tempa\chi\mathchi\textchi
\@tempa\psi\mathpsi\textpsi
\@tempa\omega\mathomega\textomega

\makeatother

\begin{document}

See \alpha\beta\gamma, but \theta\vartheta\ or \rho\varrho.\par
Normal: $a\alpha l\lambda r\rho\varrho x_{\mu}$\par
With \verb+\mathrm+: $\mathrm{a\alpha l\lambda r\rho\varrho x_{\mu}}$\par
With \verb+\bm+: $\bm{\alpha}$, but $\bm{\mathrm{\alpha}} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works really well. I did not know about the `\fam=0` trick. So far I only managed to break it by trying to use the `bm` package.

Answer (score 6):

This is easiest with `unicode-math` and lualatex or xelatex as a Unicode math font already contains both styles of mu:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{is italic mu: } & \mu \\
\text{should be upright mu: } & \symup{\mu}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would love to use modern latex, but apparently it is still too new for my collaborators, so I am stuck with good old pdflatex.

Answer (score 3):

Since you appear to use Greek letters mainly (exclusively?) in math mode, you may want to acquaint yourself with the [upgreek](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/upgreek) package, which offers macros called `\upalpha`, `\upbeta`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
slanted greek math-mode letters: & $\alpha\beta\gamma\dots\mu\nu\dots\omega$ \\
upright greek math-mode letters: & $\upalpha\upbeta\upgamma\dots\upmu\upnu\dots\upomega$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, i know this package but prefer the `alphabeta` approach. I want to use greek letters in math context only, and switch between italic and upright greek letters similarly to roman letters by using `\text` and `\mathrm` and not by typing different command like `\upmu`.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, I had mentioned the possibility of using `\unslant` on the Greeks, as done here: [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220).  However, the OP wants a macro that does it automatically.

Here, I create a macro `\mathgr{}` that employs a token cycle to check each token in the argument...if they are `\up<greek>` able, it uses the `\unslant` upon them (i.e., it only uses upgreek to determine the token's greek-ness).

Because tokcycle collects the tokens before typesetting them, things like macros and grouped arguments pose no difficulty.  For example, in the MWE, in the `\mathgr` argument, I use non-greek macros, I use groupings around an exponent, I use non greek characters, I use an active `~` token, as well as a nested `\textrm`.

The `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax of the `scalerel` package is used to preserve smaller math styles for the unslanted characters.

This approach only works in pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}% ONLY USED TO DEFINE NAMES \up...
\usepackage{tokcycle,scalerel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathgr[1]{\tokcycle
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\ifcsname up\expandafter\@gobble\string##1\endcsname
   \addcytoks{\unslant{##1}}%
    \else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}{#1}%
  \expandafter\mathrm\expandafter{\the\cytoks}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
slanted greek math-mode letters: & 
  $ab c \alpha\beta\gamma^{\pi+1}\dots\mu~\nu\dots\omega\textrm{a b c}$ \\
tokcycle + unslant & 
  $\mathgr{ab c \alpha\beta\gamma^{\pi+1}\dots\mu~\nu\dots\omega\textrm{a b c}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one was happy with the look of `upgreek` and wanted to avoid the vagaries of `\unslant`, then the token cycle can be adjusted to do so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}%
\usepackage{tokcycle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathgr[1]{\tokcycle
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\ifcsname up\expandafter\@gobble\string##1\endcsname
   \addcytoks[1]{\csname up\expandafter\@gobble\string##1\endcsname}%
    \else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}{#1}%
  \expandafter\mathrm\expandafter{\the\cytoks}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
slanted greek math-mode letters: & 
  $ab c \alpha\beta\gamma^{\pi+1}\dots\mu~\nu\dots\omega\textrm{a b c}$ \\
tokcycle + unslant & 
  $\mathgr{ab c \alpha\beta\gamma^{\pi+1}\dots\mu~\nu\dots\omega\textrm{a b c}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP seems determined to "override" `\mathrm`.  While I don't recommend replacing it, nonetheless, it can be done to automatically include the token cycle with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}% ONLY USED TO DEFINE NAMES \up...
\usepackage{tokcycle,scalerel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathgr[1]{\tokcycle
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\ifcsname up\expandafter\@gobble\string##1\endcsname
   \addcytoks{\unslant{##1}}%
    \else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}{#1}%
  \expandafter\svmathrm\expandafter{\the\cytoks}%
}

\let\svmathrm\mathrm
\renewcommand\mathrm[1]{\mathgr{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
slanted greek math-mode letters: & 
  $ab c \alpha\beta\gamma^{\pi+1}\dots\mu~\nu\dots\omega\textrm{a b c}$ \\
mathrm (tokcycle + unslant) & 
  $\mathrm{ab c \alpha\beta\gamma^{\pi+1}\dots\mu~\nu\dots\omega\textrm{a b c}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the idea of unslating the usual italic Greek letters. But my main concern is to override `\mathrm`.

Comment: @JanHajer I have added a **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer, showing how to override `\mathrm`, even though I still don't recommend it.