# Unicode greek letter or new greek letter

Tags: symbols, unicode, greek

I need chi letter as the one to the right:
 [image]

My issue is that when I either use `$\chi$` or `\textgreek{q}` I don't get what I wish to. I would also be happy with U+03C7 unicode character, but I
don't want to use XeTeX but LaTeX instead. I've read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex) but I couldn't solve my problem with this...

Comment: When you say "LaTeX", do you mean latex or pdflatex?  If the latter, then my answer here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220, may be of some use (though you just made me realize I didn't demonstrate the technique on chi).  Using that approach, with `mathptmx`, I find that `\unslant[-.15]\chi` gives a good rendition of your letter.

Comment: what document class and what fonts are you using?  (a useful answer may depend on the identity of both.)

Comment: I am using book class and times fonts.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

That's the chi in the Symbol Adobe font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\upchi}{\text{\usefont{U}{psy}{m}{n}\symbol{'143}}}

\begin{document}

X\upchi

$\upchi+X_{\upchi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]