# Can I use the same font for Greek symbols as for the main text?

Tags: fonts, greek

I currently have some issues with typing micrometer in symbols in the main text.

If I use `\mu` it is in italics, if I use `\upmu` the font changes and `\textgreek` also produces a different font.

Is there any way to set the font?

Comment: Use `\si{\um}` from `siunitx`.

Comment: See my answer here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Comment: Thank you Steven, this was exactly what I was looking for! I did find your post earlier, but I couldn't get it to work. Now it does! Thanks so much!

Comment: So I've implemented \unslant box-way, but now I seem to have a problem with the fact that it is in a serif font, while my text is sans-serif. Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `textcomp` and the command `\textmu` to get a Micron Sign fitting to your current text font.