# How to make the top heavy version of phi, with a little swirl

Tags: symbols, greek

I've attached a picture of [the species of phi I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsEh4.png) (although I'd prefer something with less head and more stem). Is this living in some package out there?

[image: 1]

Comment: Perhaps you mean `\varphi`??

Comment: Messed up the picture attachment. You should be able to see it now! It's distinct from varphi.

Comment: I would reccomend visiting [link](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), it is a program where you draw what symbol you want and it searches for the latex equivelant.

Comment: Yes! There we go - still very top heavy, but satisfactory. I was trying detexify earlier but could not get the symbol I wanted for some reason - being on a touch screen apparently made my drawing much more recognizable! Thank you.

Comment: @user193072 -- first, welcome to tex.sx.  next, what *is* this, now that you've found it?  it looks an awful lot like `\varphi` to me, although a sans serif version.  you've left us guessing ...

Comment: looks like `\upvarphi` from the upgreek package

Answer (score 6):

You could take the normal `\varphi` and, if in pdflatex, `\unslant` it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.15]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}
\begin{document}
\unslant\varphi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Based on my answer at [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220).