# Textomega symbol in equation

Tags: symbols, amsmath

Is it possible to get an exact `\textomega` like symbol in `equation`??

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
DIV=12,          
BCOR=5mm,       
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[
intlimits,
sumlimits
]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E_A =   k\,\phi\,\omega
\end{equation}

I want the same  "\textomega" \, symbol in math mode, if it's possible. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: As a side note use `` instead of " on the left side of your quote to make the quotation marks face the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since boxes are composed in text mode, by default, one merely needs, in math mode, to employ `\mbox{\textomega}` to get the upright glyph.  If smaller sizes are needed, more work would be needed.

EDITED to take Emma's very good suggestion to use `\text` rather than `\mbox` as the enabling macro.  While it requires the `amsmath` package to be loaded, it has the added benefit of adjusting itself to smaller math styles automatically.

RE-EDIT: In comments below, Andrew suggests using `\textnormal{\textomega}` instead of `\text{\textomega}`, since the latter can be adversely influenced, as in the case of theorem statements, if the prevailing environment is `\textit`.

```
\documentclass[
DIV=12,          
BCOR=5mm,       
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[
intlimits,
sumlimits
]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E_A =   k\,\phi\,\textnormal{\textomega}
\end{equation}

I want the same  "\textomega" \, symbol in math mode, if it's possible. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If pdflatex is being used, another option is to `\unslant` the regular math-mode `\omega` glyph, in the manner of this answer, [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220)

Comment: I believe `\text` also works in place of `\mbox`. That seems more natural to me.

Comment: @Emma  Thanks.  It has the added benefit of auto-adjusting to the current mathstyle (subscript, etc.)

Comment: You might want `\textnormal` instead of `\text` - otherwise you may get surprises when the surrounding text is bold or italic...

Comment: @AndrewSwann I am strugglng to come up with a use case that demonstrates your cited problem... `$\boldmath E_A =   k\,\phi\,\text{\textomega}$` does not cause any issue, `$\text{\textbf{This is \textomega}}$` makes the omega bold, but not unexpectedly.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  E.g. in a theorem statement where `\textit` is in effect, this changes the shape of the `\textomega` but not of the rest of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Claudio Beccari's Greek font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{greek}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{greek}{m}{n}{
  <5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4> 
  <17.28><20.74><24.88><29.86><35.83>
  genb*grmn
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{U}{greek}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upomega}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`w}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E_A = k\phi\upomega
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Other letters can be added. If you only need the omega, wasting a math group might be too much, here's a more economical version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{greek}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{greek}{m}{n}{
  <5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4>
  <17.28><20.74><24.88><29.86><35.83>
  genb*grmn
}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\upomega}{{\text{\usefont{U}{greek}{m}{n}w}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E_A = k\phi\upomega
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]