# Cabin and \textmu

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Something is wrong with `\textmu` when using the [`cabin`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cabin/) font package with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}
\textmu{}µm
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have checked the [Cabin font on Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/cabin) as well as the OpenType version shipped with the `cabin` package, and they both contain the µ glyph. Uncommenting the first three `\usepackage{...}` lines and compiling with either `lualatex` or `xelatex` works as expected. (I know that the OpenType version is not used when compiling with `pdflatex`. I just wanted to point out that the glyph should, in principle, exist in this font.)

Do I have to choose some other encoding? Or is there something wrong with the package?

I'm using MikTeX 2.9.6211 on Windows 10 and all packages should be up to date.

Comment: no problem with `xelatex` and/or `lualatex`

Comment: For a pdflatex situation, this answer of mine can also help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encoding file `cbn_cgvdav.enc` is faulty. It used `/mu` but a look in the pdf shows that the name of the glyph is `/uni00B5`.

That's why pdflatex complains

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/impal
lari/cabin/Cabin-Regular.pfb): glyph `mu' undefined
```

You should notify the author. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cabin

As a work-around you can make a local copy of `cbn_cgvdav.enc` and exchange the two line below the `%B0` with these lines here

```
%B0
  /degree /plusminus /uni00B2 /uni00B3 /.notdef /uni00B5 /paragraph /periodcentered
  /.notdef /uni00B9 /ordmasculine /.notdef /onequarter /onehalf /threequarters /Euro
```

Comment: In Latin-1 encoding, the "mu" glyph is not supposed to be named mu. Instead, that name blongs to a character in the Greek portion of Unicode. Alas, historically the character at Unicode 00B5 was often named either mu or mu1. If you open the font in FontForge, the program will alert you to the fact that the glyph should have been named uni00B5, not mu or mu1. AFAIK most programs know about the name-change that occured when Unicode became the norm. However, in pdflatex, this is the job of font encoding files.

Comment: @RobtA: The job of font encoding files is not naming of glyphs, but mapping of glyphs to positions. pdflatex doesn't care much about "correct" names -- you could also use "flivatu" as glyph name -- but the name used in an encoding file must be the same as the one used in the pfb.

Comment: I think the problem is with the pfb (generated by fontforge).  I've generated a pfb using cfftot1 and the \textmu glyph is displayed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I knew that! I just did not explain it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

### Update

With the release of 2017-04-02, the `pfb` files for the Cabin fonts have been fixed and the output of

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}

\textmu{}µm

\end{document}
```

is as expected

[image]

### Original answer

I tried compiling `nfssfont` with the following interactive session:

```
> pdflatex nfssfont
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/nfssfont.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No auxiliary output files.

**********************************************
* NFSS font test program version <v2.2d>
*
* Follow the instructions
**********************************************

Input external font name, e.g., cmr10
(or <enter> for NFSS classification of font):

\currfontname=


*** NFSS classification ***

Font encoding [T1]:

\encoding=TS1
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)
Font family [cmr]:

\family=Cabin-TLF
Font series [m]:

\series=
Font shape [n]:

\shape=
Font size [10pt]:

\size=
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cabin/TS1Cabin-TLF.fd)
Now type a test command (\help for help):)
*\table\bye
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]{/usr/
local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cabin/cbn_cgvdav.enc}</usr/local/
texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/impallari/cabin/Cabin-Regular.pfb

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/i
mpallari/cabin/Cabin-Regular.pfb): glyph `mu' undefined


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/i
mpallari/cabin/Cabin-Regular.pfb): glyph `onesuperior' undefined


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/i
mpallari/cabin/Cabin-Regular.pfb): glyph `threesuperior' undefined


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/i
mpallari/cabin/Cabin-Regular.pfb): glyph `twosuperior' undefined
></usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></us
r/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr
/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on nfssfont.pdf (1 page, 52627 bytes).
Transcript written on nfssfont.log.
```

If I try the same with `cmr`, the relevant row in the output is

[image]

so the mu should be in slot `"B5`. However the corresponding row with `Cabin-TLF` has

[image]

according to the warning issued during processing.

The row with `CabinCondensed-TLF` shows

[image]

It's apparent that something went wrong when building the `Cabin-Regular.pfb` file.

You should file a bug report to Bob Tennent. For the time being, you can obviate by using the condensed version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textmu}{%
  {\usefont{TS1}{CabinCondensed-TLF}{\f@series}{\f@shape}\symbol{"B5}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textmu{}µm

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The author of the [`cabin`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cabin/) package, Bob Tennent, sent to me a corrected version of the faulty file `Cabin-Regular.pfb`. (See [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s answer).

I have uploaded the corrected file here: http://www.wikiupload.com/HWPLWMIV5RG3QJ5.