# non-italic Greek letters

Tags: greek, typefaces

I wander if Greek letters can be normal - non-italic. Variants such as

```
The length is 10 \mu$\text{m}$.
```

or

```
The length is 10 $\text{\mu m}$.
```

are not accepted.

Only

```
The length is 10 $\mu \text{m}$.
```

is accepted which produces the output

[image]

To me there is a disaccord between the the italic Greek mu and the normal Latin m.

Comment: My answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220, could be of use if you use pdflatex.

Comment: When you are interested specifically in the micro-prefix and not a full Greek alphabet, there is \textmu (from the package textcomp) and \tcmu (from the package mathcomp, works in math mode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this specific case, use `siunitx`: first it is not a ‘normal’ μ which is used, and – icing on the cake, you'll have a correct unbreakable thin space between the number and the unit:

```
\documentclass{article
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

The length is \SI{10}{\um}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It you're interested in having upright Greek letters in general, you can either use the `upgreek` package, or one of the fonts that allow them in math mode, among which `fourier`, `kpfonts`, `mathdesign` (non exhaustive list).

Comment: How to properly use `siunitx` with complex units of measurement e.g. 5 N/mm^2?

Comment: Using the abbreviations: `\SI[per-mode=symbol]{5}{\N\per\square\mm}` or  `\SI[per-mode=symbol]{5}{\N\per\mm\squared}` . The list of abbreviations is in table 21, pp. 34-36 of thee documentation, and you can define your own abbreviations.

Answer (score 2):

With an up to date LaTeX installation,the UTF-8 encoding and the "textcomp" package are used by default. This makes the input of the MICRO SIGN simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The length is 10\,µm.
The length is 10\,\textmu m.
\end{document}
```

Mind, that the µ in the example is the Unicode character 00B5 MICRO SIGN.

For the similar looking character 'μ' (03BC GREEK SMALL LETTER MU) as well as for all other Greek letters, Unicode input is supported "everywhere" by loading the package [textalpha](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/greek/greek-fontenc/textalpha-doc.pdf) (see its documentation for limitations) or in text parts marked as `greek` by loading  Babel with, e.g., `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}`.