# How the get non italic greek letters like siunitx package?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, greek

I'm trying to get the `\mu` symbol exactly as `siunitx` package do, however, I failed. How can I get the `\mu` symbol, for to use it in an equation, as the `\micro` symbol obtained by `siunitx` package? How can I get other greek letters too?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$10~\mu m$\\
$\mathrm{10~\mu m}$\\
$\mathrm{10~\upmu m}$\\
\SI{10}{\micro\meter}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Is something not satisfactory with `\upalpha`, `\upbeta`, etc?

Comment: Can't you use `\si{\micro`). Note it isn't exactly a μ. If you need a real upright μ, you can use the `upgreek` package, which will  borrow it either from  Euler or Adobe Symbol.

Comment: This answer might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default siunitx uses here \textmu from the textcomp package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{upgreek,textcomp}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$10~\mu m$\\
$\mathrm{10~\mu m}$\\
$\mathrm{10~\upmu m}$\\
 \SI{10}{\micro\meter} \textmu $\text{\textmu}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should *not* use the "micro" symbol from the `siunitx` package as an upright greek lowercase letter while in math mode. From the user guide of the `upgreek` package (which provides the macro `\upmu`):

> Note that `\upmu` should normally *not* be used as the prefix for physical units, meaning `10^{−6}`. The mu symbol to be used there is to be taken from the *text* font, and most Latin text fonts do actually include a suitable Greek mu, which can be accessed as `\textmu`. Most likely –- depending on the encoding of your text fonts -– you need to load the package `textcomp` for this purpose. [emphasis in orginal]

Conversely, `\textmu` should in general not be used as a substitute for `\upmu` or `\mu` while in math mode.