# \mathrm not working with \documentclass{elsarticle}

Tags: symbols, elsarticle, times, txfonts

I am trying to type a non-italiac `\mu` in a inline math mode. The problem is related to the use of the elsarticle class. The normal method using `\mathrm{}` is not working.

Here is a MWM:

```
\documentclass[5p,times,hidelinks]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
    normal math mode $\mu$ \\
    mathrm $\mathrm{\mu}$ \\
\end{document}
```

That on my computer returns

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How the get non italic greek letters like siunitx package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389789/how-the-get-non-italic-greek-letters-like-siunitx-package)

Comment: @remco - Note a duplicate, as the information that the `elsarticle` document class is in use, along with the `txfonts` package, is relevant.

Comment: In no case `\mathrm{\mu}` produces an upright mu.

Comment: @egreg that may be true for text documents but $\mathrm{\mu}$ is how you make an upright mu in Matplotlib's latex renderer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code can't work because `\mathrm` is designed to work with Latin, not Greek, letters.

If the `elsarticle` package is loaded with the option `times`, the `txfonts` text and math font package is loaded. To generate upright Greek letters, the `txfonts` package provides the -`up` suffix method: `$\alphaup$`, `$\betaup$`, etc. For the `txfonts` case, `$\muup$` and `\si{\micro}` (with `\si` being a macro of the `siunitx` package) produce the same output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[5p,times,hidelinks]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
slanted $\mu$ 

upright $\muup$

siunitx \si{\micro}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In case it's not clear: `\si{\micro}` can be used in both text and math mode.

Comment: Thanks, it even works for `\varepsilonup`.

Comment: @AustinDowney - Indeed, the `\...up` suffix method should work with all lowercase and uppercase Greek letters — in math mode, obviously.