# How do I get upright greek letters with the mathastext package?

Tags: greek, mathastext

I am using [`mathastext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext?lang=en) and [`bm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm?lang=en) packages.

I want a **bold upright phi**. `\bm{\phi}` gives me italicized one and if I change it to a capital `\Phi`, it works.

`...
\usepackage[upgreek]{mathastext}
...`

What additional options do I need? Please give an example.
Hint: The solution exist on pg. 19-20 of `mathastext` documentation. I couldn't understand it.

Comment: According to page 40 of the documentation, the `upgreek` option only does something if you also use the `LGRgreek` option. But this changes the shape of the phi which might not be what you want.

Comment: Is using the `upgreek` package an option for you? If so, you could simply type `\bm{\upphi}`.

Comment: @Mico options `eulergreek` and `symbolgreek` of `mathastext` use same glyphs as `upgreek` package, but with `\phi`,  not `\upphi`. So if one needs both `\phi` and `\upphi` it is better to use `upgreek` package. If not one can just pass one of `eulergreek` or `symbolgreek` option to `mathastext`. Then `\MTEulerScale` and `\MTSymbolScale` commands allow to scale the fonts (where `upgreek` only provides one alternative scale for Symbol font).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @DavidPurton in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390177/how-do-i-get-upright-greek-letters-with-the-mathastext-package#comment968600_390177), the documentation of [mathastext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) indicates (but in a not so clear way) that `upgreek` option has effect only if one of the Greek related options described in `§1.9 Greek letters` is active.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upgreek, LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\[\phi, \Phi\]
\[\bm{\phi}, \bm{\Phi}\]
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

However, perhaps your font set-up has some specifics.

### Other approaches

E.g. you could use `\usepackage[upright]{fourier}...load text packages...\usepackage{mathastext}` to benefit from the Fourier set-up for Greek letters. Then `\bm{\phi}` gives a bold upright Greek letter. `mathastext` does not interfere at all in this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
% add here text packages according to what is needed
\usepackage{mathastext}% does not modify anything to Greek in math
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\[\phi, \Phi\]
\[\bm{\phi}, \bm{\Phi}\]
\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

Or use `eulergreek` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\[\phi, \Phi\]
\[\bm{\phi}, \bm{\Phi}\]
\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: independently of `mathastext`, there is also for example `\usepackage[upgreek]{txgreeks}`. It does work with `\usepackage{bm}` and `\bm{\phi}`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative...

Based on my answer at [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220), this works for bold upright by `\unslant`ing the `\bm\phi`.

This works only in `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\phi \bm\phi \unslant{\bm\phi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]