# Use upright lowercase greek with mathdesign

Tags: greek, mathdesign, isomath

After looking at the `isomath` document, I am interested in the second way of implementing lowercase upright greeks. But it seems that this method does not work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OML}{mdput}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
\(\mathbf{\pi}\pi\)
\end{document}
```

And the result is 
[image]

Comment: maybe related answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Thank you. I have already read that answer. However, I am still interested in the upright greek provided by the mathdesign package (I like its style).