# How do I get chemgreek to use κ instead of ϰ with fontspec and newcomputermodern?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, greek, chemgreek

Yesterday I appeared to find the [perfect bit of magic code for my thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576737/using-cmu-serif-upright-italic-instead-of-chemgreek?noredirect=1#comment1452124_576737), however, I noticed LaTeX is using the cursive version of kappa (ϰ) instead of the symbol chemistry uses for [denticity](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/K03366) (κ).

ϰ is GREEK KAPPA SYMBOL and κ is GREEK SMALL LETTER KAPPA.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}\usepackage{chemgreek}\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}
%\changechemgreeksymbol{fontspec}{lower}{kappa}{κ}\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}
Math mode: 
\( 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu
\)

Text mode: 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu 

ch: 
    \ch{\dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}}

Text: 
    \dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of math mode, text mode, chemmacros and the semantic commands outside of a \ch enciorment]

No trouble, `chemgreek` has an interface for changing a symbol mapping, and you can just past symbols right into `lualatex` right? That is the whole point. I uncomment out that one line from above to give:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}\usepackage{chemgreek}\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}
\changechemgreeksymbol{fontspec}{lower}{kappa}{κ}\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}
Math mode: 
\( 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu
\)

Text mode: 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu 

ch: 
    \ch{\dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}}

Text: 
    \dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}
\end{document}
```

[image: The same image as above, but the math mode kappa is correct, and only the math mode kappa]

But for some reason this ONLY works to fix the math mode symbol. Is there a way to use κ throughout? I will not need ϰ anywhere in my document if that makes things easier, so replacing it entirely is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure math mode. The text font has the “x-like” kappa.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemgreek}

\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}
\changechemgreeksymbol{fontspec}{lower}{kappa}{\ensuremath{κ}}
\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}

\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}
Math mode: 
\( 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu
\)

Text mode: 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu 

ch: 
    \ch{\dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}}

Text: 
    \dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One tweak to the excellent answer by @egreg: `\ensuremath{κ}` will give you a slanted *κ*, and you want an upright κ to match your other symbols.  Therefore, load `\ensuremath{\symup{\kappa}}` in `unicode-math`.  (With some other packages, you might want `\upkappa` or `\kappaup`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\changechemgreeksymbol{fontspec}{lower}{kappa}{\ensuremath{\symup{\kappa}}}
\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}
Math mode: 
\( 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu
\)

Text mode: 
    \chemalpha
    \chembeta
    \chemeta
    \chemkappa
    \chemmu 

ch: 
    \ch{\dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}}

Text: 
    \dento{1}\bridge{1}\hapto{1}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]