# How to print non-italic and bold Greek letters

Tags: math-mode, greek

[image]
[image]

How to write in math mode `\upsilon` and `\omega` same as on attached images?
What font/package I need to include?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a math font that has desirable shape and is compatible with your text font.  Here I chose `mathptmx`, since it looks similar to your request.  Then, if you use pdflatex, you can use this slanting approach to make the slanted letters upright.  In the MWE, I show the normal (italic) greek letters, and then below that I show the unslanted versions.

Based on my answer at [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.18]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}
$\omega\upsilon$\par
$\unslant\omega%
\unslant[-.1]\upsilon$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

It is generally a **bad idea** to mix and match fonts.  But the OP hinted at wanting to do so.  If one wanted to go that route and say, use Computer Modern italic as the default math font, but want access to the mathptmx greeks for purposes of unslanting, then this would be a way.  As you can see, they are all available in the same math environment...and they don't look good together.  There you have it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.18]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\altomega}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\altupsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"1D}
\begin{document}
$a\omega\upsilon\altomega\altupsilon$\par
$a\unslant\omega%
\unslant\upsilon
\unslant\altomega%
\unslant[-.1]\altupsilon$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Is any option to use this math font for certain letters or with custom command?

Comment: @ДенисЛяшков As I have structured it, the italic `mathptmx` becomes your default math font.  The `\unslant`ing can be applied to anything.  If you wanted a different default italic math font and `mathptmx` for *only* these letters, you would have to use an approach where you declare more than one math alphabet (search for `\DeclareMathAlphabet`), and invoke one or the other on an as-needed basis.

Comment: thank you so much! i'll try your method

Comment: @ДенисЛяшков Please see the **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer for how to do what you asked.

Comment: Dear Steven, thank you so much! It is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to obtain with a maths fonts defining the possibility to have the *french style* for greek letters via an option; e.g. `fourier, MinionPro, kpfonts`.

Here is an example with fourier:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\begin{document}

$\omega\enspace \upsilon$

\boldmath$\omega\enspace \upsilon$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In PDFLaTeX, load an upright font in OML encoding, the only 8-bit encoding that supports both Latin and Greek.  You can then use Greek letters in `\mathnormal`, `\mathrm` and `\mathbf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[rmdefault=mdput,
            OMLmathrm,
            OMLmathbf         
           ]{isomath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \omega &\quad \upsilon \\
 \mathrm{\omega} &\quad \mathrm{\upsilon} \\
 \mathbf{\omega} &\quad \mathbf{\upsilon}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Math Design Utopia sample]

You can also use `\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\omega}}`.

There are not many suitable 8-bit math fonts, but you can use `rmdefault=mdbch` with `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` and `rmdefault=mdugm` with `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}`.

Here, I use the `isomath` interface, but you could also define the math alphabets yourself with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` or `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`.

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use `unicode-math`.  All OpenType math fonts support `\symup` and `\symbfup`, and there are package options to make `\mathrm` and `\mathbf` aliases of these, for backward-compatibility with code such as the above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-otf} % Sets up Erewhon Math in unicode-math

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \omega &\quad \upsilon \\
 \symup{\omega} &\quad \symup{\upsilon} \\
 \symbfup{\omega} &\quad \symbfup{\upsilon}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```