# How to use sans-serif italic greek letter in math mode?

Tags: fonts, unicode, unicode-math, greek, sans-serif

I am typing `\mathsf{\eta X \eta^\top}` to represent 3 matrices multiplying together. I choose to use sans-serif fonts as matrices, but the greek letter `\eta` cannot be displayed as sans-serif fonts.

I do not know if any font can have **sans-serif italic greek** in math mode. STIX Two does not work.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{mathrm=sym,mathbf=sym,mathsf=sym,math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
```

`\setmathfont[range=sfit/{greek,Greek}]{STIX Two Math}` this does not work:

```
I am trying to set up alphabet"sfit/greek" but
(unicode-math)  there are no configuration settings for it. (See
(unicode-math)  source file "unicode-math-alphabets.dtx" to
(unicode-math)  debug.)
```

Comment: Unicode only has bold sans serif greek, not regular. Because...

Comment: I see this at [unimath-symbols](https://mirrors.zju.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) but why?

Comment: because the unicode math alphabet assignments are weirdly inconsistent. You can of course access them the classic way as normal math italic greek, but from a sans serif font such as tex gyre heros math, but it's a pain that that is needed

Answer (score 5):

Unicode only specifies bold sans serif Greek not regular (for no sensible reason, it's just the way it is) which makes it hard to access sans Greek in any reasonable way. here I take Sans serif from Fira Math, note this is a "classic font change" so the result have standard Unicode slots and will lose the sans serif nature if cut and pasted elsewhere, unlike the bold sans which are using the Unicode Sans Serif math slots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% First things first\unimathsetup{mathrm=sym,mathbf=sym,mathsf=sym,math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfontface{\hmmsf}[Scale = MatchLowercase]{Fira Math}
\begin{document}

1 $abc \alpha\beta\gamma$ % OK

2 $\symsf{abc \alpha\beta\gamma}$ % sigh

3 $\symsfit{abc \alpha\beta\gamma}$% sigh

4 $\symbfsf{abc \alpha\beta\gamma}$% OK

5 $\symbfsfit{abc \alpha\beta\gamma}$% OK



8 $\hmmsf{\mita\mitb\mitc \mitalpha\mitbeta\mitgamma}$ %OK


9 $\hmmsf{abc \mupalpha\mupbeta\mupgamma}$ % OK



\end{document}
```

Comment: I think "no sensible reason" boils down to the fact that the Unicode Technical Committee wanted to save space, and not assign another block.  So they punted.  Not a good decision.

Answer (score 0):

For those who seek Greek matching with Computer Modern fonts, the `fontsetup` package provides them with the New Computer Modern fonts.
[image: newcm sans greek]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \[\msansalpha\msansbeta\msansGamma\msansDelta\msanseta\]
    \[\mitsansalpha\mitsansbeta\mitsansGamma\mitsansDelta\mitsanseta\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure if the italic alpha is supposed to look like this.

Comment: I just found out that the XITS math font file contains sans serif italic greek letters, compatible with times, although I don't know how to access them.

Comment: They are present in the stixtwo math font as well, in the private area

Comment: Then there is also this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230220/128462

Comment: See if you mean **13.2.18 Bold sans serif Greek** [here](https://mirrors.zju.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf), not *regular* sans serif. Or you can see Page 49 of [this](https://mirrors.zju.edu.cn/CTAN/fonts/stix2-otf/STIXTwoMath-Regular.pdf)

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I'll probaby make a second answer for accessing the PUA stix2 characters later

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu No, I mean regular sans serif. One can see the glyphs in fontforge. The ones in stix2 are in PUA, the ones in xits are not. I don't really understand what's going on in the xits ones. In fontforge, I see a sans serif italic alpha with the info 4022 (0xfb6) U+1D6FC "u1D6FC.ss" MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL ALPHA. When I type access it using `\symbol{"1D6FC}`, I get the normal, serif italic small alpha.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the xits ones are stylistic sets. One should be able to use them using `StylisticSet=` when loading the font.