# How to access non-Unicode glyphs from OTFs with Lua(La)TeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload

I opened [Shobhika](https://ctan.org/pkg/shobhika) font in FontForge and it has certain glyphs which I am guessing aren't encoded in Unicode (if I understand this business correctly). E.g., have a look at the following slot.

[image: 1]

What I guessed from this is that the slot I have selected is a non-Unicode position because I see `U+????`. Is there any way to load this shape by calling either `65664`/`0x10080`/`BhaRa.dv`? Disclaimer: I don't know what all of them mean, I am just guessing they are different types of identifier for this shape. Which of these identifiers are understood by TeX (especially LuaTeX)? I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420214) solution, but it didn't work for the glyph I want.

Comment: You are right about your guess. It is not clear to me what macro package you use, but for ConTeXt, you can get them by using `\resolvedglyphdirect`. Works both for luatex and luametatex. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtEts.png) is an example output from the `BhaRa.dv`.

Comment: @mickep I am using LaTeX :'(

Comment: Although what I want is exactly this. A command which will simply take an argument with one of these identifiers and print the glyph. Do you know a LaTeX-way to do this?

Comment: I used "n:BhaRa.dv", that takes the name. It seems there are alternatives in that command. So, good, now you know that it is possible in luatex at least. I am sure somebody else will help you with the latex way of doing it.

Comment: @mickep I meant LuaLaTeX, not the plain one. If this is possible in LuaTeX, then it should also work with LuaLaTeX, right?

Comment: Yes, it seems not you have gotten the answer that you need. Good luck with the TeXing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `slot_of_name` from `luaotfload`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Shobhika}
\begin{document}
The BhaRa.dv character is:
\directlua{tex.sprint("\\char" .. luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(), [[BhaRa.dv]]))}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also enter the code directly with `\char[code]` if you know the slot number. I am not entirely sure how the codes correspond to the values that FontForge shows. You can however print the font table with numbers that `\char` understands with the following code, adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666152/ (which is itself adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98789/). The code is basically a for-loop around `slot_of_name` for each character.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setmainfont{Shobhika Regular}

\newfontface\OD{Shobhika-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}\noindent
\begin{luacode*}
local f = fontloader.open('/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/shobhika/Shobhika-Regular.otf')
local glyphs = {}
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)

for i = 1, #glyphs do
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
      tex.sprint(glyphs[i].unicode .. ": ")
      tex.sprint("{\\OD\\char" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "}");
   else
      local charcode = luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(), glyphs[i].name)
      tex.sprint("{\\tiny " .. tostring(charcode) .. ":}")
      if (charcode ~= false) then
         tex.sprint("{\\OD\\char" .. charcode .. "}")
      end
   end
   tex.sprint("\\ {\\small(" .. string.gsub(glyphs[i].name, "_", "\\_") .. ")}\\\\")
end
fontloader.close(f)
\end{luacode*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Small part of the output:

[image]

Now for example ShaVa.dv can be printed with `\char984278` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for me, but I want to discuss a few things. First of all, there is an absolute path in your code because of which it wasn't compiling on my machine. It would be great to not have it and ask the user to have Shobhika-Regular.otf in the working directory.

Comment: The other question is, if I don't have `\setmainfont` command with Shobhika, the output doesn't show the non-standard glyphs. They only show up when I set Shobhika as the main font. What might be the reason?

Comment: @Niranjan without the absolute path it did not work on my machine, so I left it in. Of course some changes may be needed for different users, as is often the case when working with filenames or other operating system-related operations. This is not "production code", I hope it can serve as a starting point for you and others to achieve the results they want.

Comment: @Marjin, sure! That's alright.

Comment: For the main font: this is most likely related to `slot_of_name` taking `font.current()` as an argument, which is a register number that is connected in some way to `\setmainfont`. I didn't look into it further but there is probably a way to get the number index of secondary fonts to use as the argument to `slot_of_name`.

Comment: @Marjin Okay, maybe a `fontspec`-problem, will ask a separate question for that. I have a last question to you regarding this. I tried your code with another font I am currently testing (can't share it as I don't have the rights). I followed the _exact_ same steps like looking into the glyph name with FontForge and using it in the code you have given, but weirdly I get bad character code error with that font. I tried forming the character table with the other code and issued `\char[code]` command. It works, but I get a tofu. What might be wrong with it?

Comment: Oh, apparently using `Renderer=Harfbuzz` was creating a problem. I have no idea why, but removing it works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Be aware that these indices are not stable. After an update of the font, LuaLaTeX, luaotfload or some settings they will often refer to different glyphs.

Comment: Can this method be used to access glyphs in private use areas of some math fonts, such as stix two math?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I made a easy-to-use macro with `\def\myglyph#1{\directlua{tex.sprint("\\char" .. luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(),[[#1]]))}}}`. It should be safe, right? As it would compute the index number on-the-fly. Of course I am guessing the font-developer shouldn't change the internal name that they have set once.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420167/174620) answer your question?

Comment: @Niranjan Thanks. But for reasons that I don't understand, I cannot use the methods in that answer to use the private use area glyphs in math mode. They seem to work outside math mode.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis, Ask a separate question, showing what you tried. (For example, math mode uses its own fonts; what did your code do?)

Comment: @Cicada David Carlisle has said that he shall write an answer later, regarding this. I just thought this method might work perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693724/how-to-use-sans-serif-italic-greek-letter-in-math-mode/693745?noredirect=1#comment1721770_693745