What is the simplest way to have upright bold greek letters?
Apparently greek letters must be placed in math mode to be compiled and display.  When I type $\bm{\theta}$ it's automatically italicized.  I tried $\textbf{\theta}$, $\bm{\textbf{\theta}}$, $\bm{\rm{\theta}}$, $\bm{\mathrm{\theta}}$, and $\mathbf{\theta}$, but they either won't compile or keep the letter italicized.  Apparently I could use isomath or a different package but I'm amazed LaTeX made such a simple idea so complicated to code.  I don't like the font from the upgreek package.  Any advice is appreciated!  My focus is primarily on use with other math in math mode.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern

Are you looking to typeset Greek text, as opposed to typesetting math that may contain Greek letters? Please advise.

@Mico - Sometimes the former, sometimes the latter.  It would be good to know how to handle both situations.

TeX's text and math modes are fundamentally different. As it currently stands, your question is overly broad. Please consider asking two separate questions, one focused on how to typeset Greek text (as opposed to text based on the Latin, Cyrillic, Hebrew, Arabic etc alphabets), the other focused on how to enter Greek uppercase and lowercase letters in math-y situations.

@Mico - In that case, I'll just worry about the math use since that's where I'm using them in the vast majority of my document.

Any decent introduction to TeX's math mode will inform you that \mathbf and \mathrm are meant to be used with Latin letters, not Greek letters. \textbf should never be used in math mode to begin with. (Does the fact that the macro's name contains the string "text" maybe give you a clue as to how it's supposed to be used?)


What is the simplest way to have upright bold greek letters [in math mode]?

IMNSHO, the simplest way is to use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile your document, to load the unicode-math package, and to use that package's \symup and \symbfup macros to render the arguments with upright and upright-bold glyphs.
If you want all math-mode letters, be they Latin, Greek, or whatever, rendered using upright glyphs, you may do so by loading the unicode-math package with the option math-style=upright.

% compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % for "\sym.." macros
\newcommand\blurb{\gamma\theta\omega\Gamma\Theta\Omega}
\newcommand\blurbx{%
   $\blurb \quad \symup{\blurb} \quad \symit{\blurb}$\par
   $\symbf{\blurb} \quad \symbfup{\blurb} \quad \symbfit{\blurb}$}

\begin{document}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
\blurbx

\smallskip
\setmathfont{Fira Math} 
\blurbx

\end{document}

